# How to remove trix from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

With rails 5.2, I was using trix-gem. After upgrade to rails 6.0, I have the following error message in the js console :

```js
trix.js:1417 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "trix-toolbar" has already been used with this registry at http://localhost:3000/packs/js/application-9c991ca5ea3ec87c7961.js:36753:181
```

Of course, I have removed the trix-gem in the gemfile, but I think I always have 2 trix.js in my rails app, how can I fix it  ?

Comment: After removing from `Gemfile`, did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: I found my mistake : I had forget an old call to the trix.js in the admin's header